# How to correctly write SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all products, where top root category is active. So I have created stored procedure **WITH_EMULATOR** based on that article [WITH RECURSIVE and MySQL](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html) to get root category.
**Default query**:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_products 
INNER JOIN shop_category ON (shop_products.category_id=shop_category.id)
WHERE shop_products.active=1
AND (SELECT sc.active FROM shop_category as sc WHERE sc.id = shop_category.parent_id) = 1
```

And then I tried to do it in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_products 
INNER JOIN shop_category ON (shop_products.category_id=shop_category.id)
WHERE shop_products.active=1
AND (CALL WITH_EMULATOR(
"EMPLOYEES_EXTENDED",
"
  SELECT ID, PARENT_ID, ACTIVE
  FROM shop_category as sc
  WHERE sc.ID = shop_category.parent_id
",
"
    SELECT P.ID, P.PARENT_ID, P.ACTIVE
    FROM shop_category AS P INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES_EXTENDED C ON C.PARENT_ID = P.ID
",
"
  SELECT ACTIVE
  FROM EMPLOYEES_EXTENDED
  WHERE PARENT_ID = 0
  ORDER BY id
",
0,
""
)) = 1
```

But I got an error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL WITH_EMULATOR(
"EMPLOYEES_EXTENDED",
"
  SELECT ID, PARENT_ID, ACTIVE
' at line 4
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**shop_category:**

```
id | parent_id | name               | active
1    NULL        Literature           1
2    1           Interesting books    1
3    2           Horrible books       1
4    1           Books to burn        1
5    NULL        Motorized vehicles   0
6    5           Cars                 1
7    6           Motorbikes           1
```

**shop_products:**

```
id | category_id | name
1    7             Cooking for dummies
2    7             Twilight saga
3    7             My grandpa's car
```

According to this example I should get nothing, because category with id 7 has root parent active = 0.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon version is 5.7

Comment: With recursive is not available until version 8.0

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, that's why I'm using stored procedure

Comment: Ah i didn't read far enough!

Comment: add your table structure please

Comment: I would suggest to slightly change your data model and add/use transitive closure table as explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure from a select statement in mysql. Period.